# Magento 2 - Entity Type empty in import /export pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, importexport

I am new to Magento. I want to develop a site in Magento 2 and the old site is in opencart. I want to import its products to Magento 2 via CSV file so I add some products to Magento 2 store with categories but in import/export pages no entity type in dropdown so please help me coz I am unable to import or export data.

Here are the screenshots of both pages below:

Import page

[image]

Export page
[image]

PLEASE tell me why it's not showing the options such as products, categories etc..

i will be very thankful to u for this kindness

Comment: Any update what was the reason for it ? I´m having the same issue in my site. Entity type dropdown is empty for exports and imports. I´m using 2.3.6. I´ĺl appreciate any help. Thanks